# opencv android-edge detection

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I am creating a project in android ,where i need to detect the `edges` of the `object` in very intial stage.But the `edges` are not appropriate they are broken .I have tried otsu `thresholding` method for `edge detection`.
Now i m trying to get the intensity from histogram ,can anyone help me to figure out the mean from the `histogram` of an image using `calchist` method in `opencv`. Also, i am giving a thought to dividing the image into blocks of 3* 3,as then computing each block.,but enable to find how to do that .
I am using `opencv` library.

Thanks,
Please do respond.

Answer (score 0):

Canny, sobel,prewitt and many edge detection algorithms perform edge detection.
But, as you said,they remain incapable to extract all edges.
You can use some edge linking algorithms to link those broken edges.
I used ant colony algorithm(genetic algorithm) to make the image understandable.
But there are dozens of linking algorithm you can use.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to figure out this. does it work ,if i split an image into blocks and perform edge detection in each block and further combine them.@FreeMan

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to figure out this. does it work ,if i split an image into blocks and perform edge detection in each block and further combine them - @FreeMan